# pgfplotstables tag is misnamed

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

The [pgfplotstables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstables) tag should be called [pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable), since that's the name of [the package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable). Could it be renamed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a good suggestion. I renamed the tag to [pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstable). I did not keep [pgfplotstables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstables) as synonym, because the name is very similar and before a user has finished typing the name I assume he would have noticed the automatic tag completion, so [pgfplotstables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplotstables) would hopefully no reappear.