# Incorrect leading when using tag links

Tags: bug, status-completed, tagging, design

When using tag links like [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug), some extra leading is added between the line with the link and the following, leading to unnecessary whitespace. I've tested this with Firefox 8.0 on Windows XP and Linux Mint 12, and with Internet Explorer 8.0.6 on Windows XP. No extra space is added above the line containing the tag link, as can be observed in Stefan's answer to [pgfplotstables tag is misnamed](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/pgfplotstables-tag-is-misnamed). While not overly dramatic, it doesn't look very elegant. Probably something that can easily be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build. Thanks for catching this bug.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reaction, looks fine now!

Comment: @Jin: I think the bug persists in the editing preview: http://i.stack.imgur.com/xGGWi.png

Comment: @doncherry you're right I forgot about the preview. it will be fixed in the next build.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the [stylesheet file](http://cdn.sstatic.net/texmeta/all.css) you can see that this behaviour seems to be intended:

```
.post-tag {
    font-size:13px;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#444;
    text-decoration:none;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:visible;
    height:14px;
    margin:2px 2px 6px 0;
    line-height:12px;
}
```

In this case the second last line is of interest:

```
margin:2px 2px 6px 0;
```

It states that there is a spacing of `2px` above, `2px` at the right, `6px` below and `0px` on the left.<sup>1</sup> So I would't name it a bug as it's the normal behaviour of the browser to display it this way. It's rather a design issue than a bug but you're right, it looks ugly.

---

<sup>1</sup> See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-margin for more information.